# Environment variable exported using bash script not accessible in python

Tags: python-3.x, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have two files :

1. run.sh
2. train.py

Content of both file
in run.sh

```
export TRAINING_DATA=test1
export FOLD=test2
python.exe train.py
```

in train.py

```
from os import environ
print(environ.get("TRAINING_DATA"), environ.get("FOLD"))
```

when I run the bash file through command line

```
bash run.sh
```

Instead of getting test1 & test2, I am getting None, None
Both the files are placed in the Scripts folder of my virtualenv. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Can you add `print(environ.get('PATH'))` under `from os...` to see if you get anything ?

Comment: @SaurabhRai: Paste the following line into your bash shell, and let us know what output you see: `FOO=bar python -c 'import os; print(os.environ.get("FOO"))'`

Comment: @Philippe : After adding ```print(environ.get('PATH')```  under ```from os import environ```, I get the values of my PATH environment variable which I guess is the expected output

Comment: Output of ``` FOO=bar python.exe -c 'import os; print(os.environ.get("FOO"))'```
was ```None```. Note: I had to use python.exe instead for python because for some reason i am not able to invoke python interpreter in my bash shell using python keyword

Comment: I assume that you do not have python installed that you can use with Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are hitting is that you are running the windows version of python.exe rather than the linux/bash version.

In the run.sh i see that you are refering to python.exe, this is the windows exe and as such when it runs it will not be in the same shell as the .sh script used to invoke it.

you can prove this to yourself by doing the following from within WSL

```
➜  which python.exe
/mnt/c/Python27/python.exe
➜  which python
/usr/bin/python
```

So as long as you have python installed in WSL you can simply swap out the .exe in the .sh script so that you are using the bash/linux version thus:

```
export TRAINING_DATA=test1
export FOLD=test2
python train.py
```

Comment: This actually helped point me in the right direction. There was no python installed on my WSL. I just enabled WSL to run the bash script. I have now installed python on my WSL and have replaced ```python.exe``` with ```python3``` command and now I am getting the desired output. Thanks. Only downside is that I have to now maintain python dependencies on WSL too :(.

Answer (score -1):

You should try disconnect and log back in on the session.
Happened to me and it's how I solved it.
On my side it was on a ssh console.
Have a great day/night-

Comment: @Alex...can you please elaborate what you mean by disconnect, I am calling my run.sh file via ```bash run.sh```. Do you mean, restart my system after installing WSL and kali distribution, then yes i did that.